# How best to read data from AWS Athena to process in a pyspark data frame?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I uploaded a file to an S3 bucket and I can read it through AWS Athena.

Now I need to read this data from the S3 backet, with pyspark to make my changes and load it into another athena table (S3).

My doubt is:

What is the best way to do this? I'm currently using spark.sql:

```
df = spark.sql(f" SELECT sector, employee, employee_quantity FROM company"
```

Is there a more performative or elegant way to run this query?

Comment: In this case there isn't a performative way because you're doing a simple query. I recommend you to read and understand about Spark Query Plans and how it works. About "how to write in an elegant way" this is only opinion based, to me, writing SQL is ugly and hard to give maintaince, if this code was mine I would change to PySpark.

Comment: The simple query was just for example, but how would you do the same query in pyspark? Thanks for being the comment

Comment: Are you using AWS Glue as catalog?

Comment: Yes, I use Aws glue

Comment: The only difference would be: `spark.table('company').select('sector', 'employee', 'employee_quantity')`

Comment: Okay, I'll test doing it this way, thank you very much for your help